# как получить выбранное значение и отправить его в абзацах

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, не так давно я начал изучать JavaScript и столкнулся с трудностью в решении задачи. В моем JS-скрипте я отправляю значение, выбранное в абзац с классом `.selected_index_value` пока все хорошо, но задача сейчас в другом, не отправлять значение только первому найденному абзацу, а всем существующим на странице с таким же идентификатором. Если у вас есть идеи, как это делается, пожалуйста, помогите мне.

Мой код и все проверенные варианты:

1. `getElementsByClassName`

   ```js
   document.getElementById('item1').onchange = function(){ 
       document.getElementsByClassName('selected_index_value')[0].innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML; 
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <select id="item1" name="Item 1">
         <option></option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
       </select>
   <p class="selected_index_value"></p>
   <p class="selected_index_value"></p>
   ```

2.`querySelector`

```js
document.getElementById('item1').onchange = function(){
    document.querySelector(".selected_index_value").innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;        
}
```

```html
<select id="item1" name="Item 1">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<p class="selected_index_value"></p>
<p class="selected_index_value"></p>
```

Пока только так но с document.getElementById() не пробовал а то знаю что не получится, и еше если я удалю выше индекс 0 `getElementsByClassName()[0]` то вообше не работает.

Фрагмент также размещен на codepen [Codepen.com](https://codepen.io/SergiuC121/pen/zYpExXV?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так нужно?

```js
document.getElementById('item1').onchange = function () {

  const collection = document.querySelectorAll('.selected_index_value');
  for (const item of collection) {
    item.innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  }

}
```

```html
<select id="item1" name="Item 1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<p class="selected_index_value"></p>
<p class="selected_index_value"></p>
```